# Publisher/editor becomes paranoid and ends up killing someone, discovers he is living a story written by his assistant

Tags: identify-this-movie

A few years ago I watched a movie that opens with a somewhat arrogant editor/publisher type guy who keeps promising to get around to reading his assistant/secretary's manuscript, but never does.

Some weird stuff starts to happen and he finds out that someone is watching him and he gets pretty paranoid.  At one point he sees someone in a nearby apartment watching him with a telescope, and he breaks in to find that it's the aforementioned assistant.  She claims to be stalking him out of romantic interest, so he continues thinking someone else is after him and ends up killing a security guard in his paranoia.

Eventually we learn that the security guard and some other people were aspiring actors hired by the assistant.  The man reads her manuscript and realizes that it's the story of what just happened to him — she orchestrated everything in order to blackmail him into publishing her books.

Can anyone identify this movie?  [This question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/34865/218) reminded me of it, but neither answer is what I'm thinking of.

Comment: I think you just spoiled a really good movie for me. I'm not completely blameless, because I knew the risk before reading it but still, I think you should put most of it in the spoiler markup.

Comment: I think it would look too much like the other question I linked if I hid the specifics, making it pointless to read for those who don't want spoilers.  I would suggest avoiding this tag, since it's completely unpredictable as to whether it will be something you've already seen or care about being spoiled.  Besides, this isn't a new movie.

Comment: This is my first question here though so if there's a spoiler policy I don't know about please point me to it :).  I think the title is not a spoiler, otherwise I think I am following http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/a/81/218 and http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/82/218

Comment: I think you're right about the spoiler policy on this site. But still, I think at least you should've hidden the paragraph where you revealed the answer to the protagonist's question and the antagonist's motive which are obviously two most important things in this kind of movies. But that's just me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like [The Killing Floor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0756672/combined) from 2007 with Marc Blucas and Shiri Appleby.

> David Lamont, a book publisher who is known to be ruthless toward friends, foes, and clients alike, moves into his new penthouse apartment. There he meets his mysterious and beautiful neighbor, Audrey Levine, who lives on the third floor. [...] Soon after he starts receiving packages with the crime scene photos that apparently were taken in his penthouse. Later he begins to receive video tapes documenting his every move and believes someone is after him. With his assistant, Rebecca Fay, David begins to discover who or what is behind everything that is occurring.

The whole thing was set up by his assistant after he didn't read her story. Here's the trailer:

Comment: That's it, thank you.  I had forgotten many of the horror elements, in my mind is was more murder-mystery.